# Is "trivially copyable" enough for the same passing conventions as a raw pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, type-traits

I want my custom `Ptr<T>` pointer class to produce equivalent assembly as a raw pointer `T *`. In particular, when passing in and out of functions, I want it to be passed in registers (just like `T *` is), not on stack.

By experimenting, I found out that at least gcc 4.9.2 requires the `Ptr<T>` to be [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable), then it produces identical assembly as raw pointer for all situations that I tried (using registers). If it is not trivially copyable, then it uses stack, not registers.

It doesn't seem to be required to be a [standard layout type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) nor [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType) (i.e. having a trivial default constructor in addition to being trivially copyable).

Can I count on this on all platforms or is this compiler dependent?

What are the recommendations for a custom class (in terms of the traits above), so that it is equivalent to raw pointers in terms of the generated assembly code (when optimizations are on)?

The actual `Ptr<T>` class is implemented in [Trilinos](http://trilinos.org/) in [Teuchos_PtrDecl.hpp](https://github.com/trilinos/trilinos/blob/931fa121ce1d5e06585dae84891676a6f309b7a9/packages/teuchos/core/src/Teuchos_PtrDecl.hpp) and [Teuchos_Ptr.hpp](https://github.com/trilinos/trilinos/blob/931fa121ce1d5e06585dae84891676a6f309b7a9/packages/teuchos/core/src/Teuchos_Ptr.hpp). It has Debug and Release versions (using ifdefs), the Debug version checks (i.e. raises a nice exception) for dangling pointers (e.g. if you get a `Ptr<T>` instance using `RCP<T>::ptr()`, where `RCP` is a reference counted pointer in Trilinos). In the Release mode, the `Ptr<T>` should be as fast as a raw pointer, and that's what I am concerned about in this question. The idea is to test a code in Debug mode for all possible user input, and if it doesn't trigger any Debug exceptions, one then switches to the Release version with the same code for production runs and it has raw pointers performance. In Release mode, the class is equivalent to:

```
enum ENull { null };

template<class T>
class Ptr {
public:
    // Constructors from other types
    inline Ptr(ENull null_in=null) : ptr_(0) {}
    inline explicit Ptr(T *ptr) : ptr_(ptr) { }
    template<class T2> inline Ptr(const Ptr<T2>& ptr) : ptr_(ptr.get()) {}

    // We want Ptr to be TriviallyCopyable, so we must use the default copy
    // constructor and assingment, default move constructor and assignment and
    // default destructor.
    ~Ptr() = default;
    inline Ptr(const Ptr<T>&) = default;
    Ptr<T>& operator=(const Ptr<T>&) = default;
    inline Ptr(Ptr&&) = default;
    Ptr<T>& operator=(Ptr&&) = default;

    inline T* operator->() const { return ptr_; }
    inline T& operator*() const { return *ptr_; }
    inline T* get() const { return ptr_; }
    inline T* getRawPtr() const { return get(); }
    inline const Ptr<T> ptr() const { return *this; }
private:
    T *ptr_;
};
```

Here is a full test code + generated assembly compiled with gcc 4.8.2: https://gist.github.com/certik/9598dc3f01608e350efd

This class is trivially copyable, standard layout type, but not trivially default constructable (thus not trivial or POD). One can add for example:

```
public:
    int i;
```

to make it not standard layout type (but still trivially copyable) and by examining the assembly code, it still has the same assembly as a raw pointer. On the other hand, if one gets rid of the trivially copyable trait (for example by adding some virtual function, or implementing some of the copy or move constructors or assignments), then the assembly will not be equivalent (rather `Ptr<T>` will be passed on a stack).

Comment: This depends on the platform ABI.

Comment: I see. Do you think that the recommendation would then be to implement as many traits (like trivially copyable, standard layout type, trivial default constructor) as possible in order to increase chances of getting the same passing conventions as a raw pointer (on other platforms than the one I tried)?

Comment: You haven't shown us the functionality of the class.  I think it'd be a more productive conversation if you showed us what it's supposed to do then discussed actual decisions about e.g. non-trivial default constructors or whatever, as we'd be able to consider the implications to usability and correctness.

Comment: @TonyD I've added full detailed background info + code of the Ptr<T> class, so that we can discuss a particular implementation. I would like to know which traits are necessary for achieving the same code generation as for raw pointers on as many platforms as possible. It looks like "trivially copyable" and "standard layout type" could work, but perhaps also "trivially default constructable" should be implemented? On my particular platform, just "trivially copyable" seems enough, but I would like the code to be platform independent.

Comment: @OndřejČertík To get an accurate answer, you'll need to survey ABIs of interest.  For example, [the Itanium ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html)'s 3.1.1 indicates determination based on "non-trivial copy constructor or destructor", reflecting customisation points for copy-by-value creation of the function argument, and destruction on return.  It looks like you should be good there, and likely on most platforms - but hopefully the insight that ABIs specify this stuff is enough to let you research support.